Azure webapp occasionally just crashes - may be stack overflow, but not much info available
I am getting a crash on an Azure Web app (.net core 6)
it seems to be working fine, then suddenly memory available drops by 1GB ish (in a minute or so), and profiling is automatically started.  Memory then drops some more and the app crashes within a few minutes and is restarted by Azure.
Every time this occured and a memory dump was captured (3 times out of say 6) I've found that the mht file memory dump diagnostics report has found a StackOverflowException and a OutOfMemoryException in the heap, but with no further info on either of them at all!  I know stackoverflows are a pain as they corrupt the stack!
But I cant figure out how to get further diagnostics info to help me fix this one.
There didnt seem to be anything interesting in the event log.
Ive looked in the application insights Trace table - it shows the app working ok, and then restarting!
I've looked in app insights Exceptions table - empty in and around the time frame
I've looked in app insights Requests table - nothing interesting, altho there is a GET / call right before it crashed, which returned a 307.  I'm presuming this is nothing interesting!
Dependencies table is also pretty uninteresting, apart from a profiler.monitor.azure.com | cid-v1:ec713804-e1e8-4b91-a3a5-f28b89ec??? right before/at the failure!
Can anyone offer any guidance to help me solve this?

Did you get the dump file and analyze it back in your dev environment with visual studio (or other analysis tools)?

I did, but not very interesting.
My current theory is that a Azure Auto Heal was set up (by me!) to do CaptureKillAnalyse, perhaps at too high/low a threshold, and it was therefore being triggered when the system was busy, and killing it.  Problem is cant find anything in the logs to suggest that this is happening.  It should be explicitly logged somewhere.
